# How to decompress a string such as "a3b3" to aaabbb?

Tags: java, compression

I'm trying to take user input like `a3b3` and decompress it to `aaabbb`. This is the code I came up with, and it prints `a33b`.

```
String getDecompressedText() {
    int i;
    int n = 1;
    String d = "";
    for (i = 0; i < compressedText.length(); i++){
        if (Character.isDigit(compressedText.charAt(i)) == true) {
            while (n < compressedText.charAt(i)-'0') {
                d += compressedText.charAt(i);
                n++;
            }
        }
        else
            d += compressedText.charAt(i);
    }
    return d;
```

Comment: Same homework I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131787/run-length-decompression

Comment: The  same question was posted yesterday and it was answered. Let us know if you can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

here's your algorithm now:

```
for each character:
  if it's not a digit, print it
  if it is a digit, print the digit itself "digit - 1" times
```

not ideal. A few issues:

- you printing the digit, not the letter preceding it. Use `charAt(i-1)`
- you increment `n`, but never reset it back to `1`. You should do that in the `for` loop.
- you should indeed print the letter `n - 1` times, since it got printed out once all by itself, so that's good
- use a `StringBuilder`
- the algorithm will break for things like `a14` - 2-digit counts.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String compressedText = "a3b3";
    int i;
    int n = 1;
    String d = "";
    for (i = 0; i < compressedText.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(compressedText.charAt(i))) {
            while (n < compressedText.charAt(i) - '0') {
                d += compressedText.charAt(i - 1);
                n++;
            }
            n = 0;
        } else {
            d += compressedText.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Output:

> aaabbbb

2 issues:

```
d += compressedText.charAt(i - 1); // Take the previous character, no the '3'

n = 0; // Reset the counter
```

Some notes:

- Use a `StringBuilder` for concatenation in a loop
- This will only work for single-digit numbers (0 - 9)

Comment: nevermind, you're right. apologies